# Mass Assignment Security Error when testing new action with Agile Web tutorial using Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am going through the Agile Web tutorial with some slight changes. When I run functional tests in Rails 3.2, I am getting the following error:

```
test_should_get_new(OrdersControllerTest):
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: cart, deal
```

Here is the orders_controller_test.rb code:

```
test "should get new" do
  cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  LineItem.create(cart: cart, deal: deals(:one))

  get :new
  assert_response :success
end
```

Here is the orders fixtures:

```
one:
  name: MyString
  address: MyText
  email: MyString
  pay_type: Check
```

Here is the line items fixtures:

```
one:
  deal: one
  order: one
```

Here is the deals fixture:

```
one:
  title: MyString
  description: MyText
  image_url: MyString
  price: 9.99
```

Here is the order controller code:

```
def new
  @cart = current_cart
  if @cart.line_items.empty?
    redirect_to store_url, notice: "Your cart is empty"
    return
  end

  @order = Order.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @order }
  end
end
```

I tried using FactoryGirl but still got the same error message. Here is the code:

```
test "should get new" do
  cart = FactoryGirl.build(:cart)
  session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  LineItem.create(cart: cart, deal: deals(:one))

  get :new
  assert_response :success
end
```

And the FactoryGirl code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do  
  factory :cart do
  end
end
```

For FactoryGirl I also tried 'create' instead of 'build' and got the same error message.

Although I could turn off the mass assignment error in config, I would rather not since I prefer to test properly.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I think the error is from `LineItem#create`. Can you post your code for the LineItem model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `LineItem.create(cart: cart, deal: deals(:one))` try

```
item = LineItem.create
item.cart = cart
item.deal = deals(:one)
```

or in your LineItem model, add:

```
attr_accessible :cart, :deal
```

Comment: The 2nd option worked. When I tried the 1st, I got an error message saying 'Expected response to be a <:success>, but was <302>'. Will the attr_accessible leave me vulnerable to anything? I figure as long as people can't modify the price it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

In your '**models**', '**order.rb**' add the **attr_accessible** line

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy  
attr_accessible :name, :address, :email, :pay_type

end
```